# PyQt5 window doesn't show

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have PyQt5 recently installed using pip3 install PyQt5 on Python 3.6.0 (Windows 10). 
All code examples that I could find didn't work, they ran just fine, but the window never appeared. For example this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    a = w.show()



    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Looks like it enters app.exec_() and doesn't show the window and never returns. Please advise.

Comment: Try running from the cmd, maybe you get some error message. I think you do not have the necessary .dlls.

Comment: Running from the cmd worked. What's missing in the IDE? I'm using Sublime text 2.